# format 12 by 12 multiplication table

Tags: java

My program outputs the table like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  
2  4  6  8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  
3  6  9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  
4  8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48  
5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  
6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  
7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  
8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96  
9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99  108  
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120  
11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  110  121  132  
12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108  120  132  144
```

I need to make it look a little better. Need your help.

This is my code:

```
int a;
int b;
for (a=1; a<=12; ++a)
{
    for (b=1; b<=12; ++b)
    {
        System.out.print(a*b+"  ");  
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Check this method - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Comment: You can check this link for detailed explenation on output formatting
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html

Comment: Please define "a little better"

Answer (score 6):

Use String `System.out.printf("")`. Like:

```
System.out.printf("%4d",a*b);
```

**or**

```
System.out.print(String.format("%4d",a*b));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in order to format your output.

```
System.out.printf("%4d", (a*b));
```

Check the syntax for the format argument [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Try to give tab space

```
System.out.print(a * b + "\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;
    for (a = 1; a <= 12; ++a) {
        for (b = 1; b <= 12; ++b) {
            sum = a * b;
            System.out.print(sum);
            if(sum < 10){
                System.out.print("    ");
        }else if(sum >= 100){
            System.out.print("  ");
        }else if(sum >= 10){
            System.out.print("   ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    int b;
    for (a = 1; a <= 12; ++a) {
        for (b = 1; b <= 12; ++b) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", (a*b));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`System.out.print(a*b+"\t");`

which uses a escape sequence that will tab each value appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to use a table like here

```
response.getWriter().append("<table><body>");
        for (int i = 1; i < width +1 ; i++) {
            response.getWriter().append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 1; j < height +1; j++) {
                response.getWriter().append("<td>").append(String.format("%4d",i*j)).append("</td>");
            }
            response.getWriter().append("</tr>");
        }
        response.getWriter().append("</body></table>");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class JavaApplication21 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1;i<13;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=12;j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d x %d = %d  \n",i,j,(i*j));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package rest;
public class doubt {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {   
            for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%4d",i*j);//+i*j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }     
 }
```