# how do I print a mathematical times table in java (the Whole times table of a certain number)

Tags: java, python, php

I am learning programing and recently got a challenge to print a mathematical times table of a certain number entered by a user. Lets say the number entered is 10, then the table should be printed as below.

[image]

I managed to print the times table of the entered number with the below codes. But not the whole table of that number.

```
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    int input= scan.nextInt();
    
    int value=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=input; i++){
     value= i*input;
     System.out.println(value);
    }
    
       Output: 
       10
       20
       30
       40
       50
       60
       70
       80
       90
       100
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       BUILD SUCCESS
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly Assist,it will also be helpful  if i can learn to do the same in python and PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [format 12 by 12 multiplication table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065228/format-12-by-12-multiplication-table)  And please do not abuse multiple tags for different programming languages/technologies, make your questions more focused.

Comment: Since you need 10 rows, with 10 columns per row, you'd need a nested loop. I see no attempt at that.

Comment: For Python--[Properly formatted multiplication table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415384/properly-formatted-multiplication-table)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of your output is to print a matrix form solution, so the better option is to use two for nested loops, the matrix that you will print is (input x input) size.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = scan.nextInt();

for(int i=1; i<=input; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=input; j++){
        System.out.print(i*j + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

This will be the output for input 10:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Comment: I will check if I can also apply the answer with Python and PHP